# How to stream a video with VLC in a LAN

Tags: vlc, streaming

I wish to execute a video in my PC and stream it in the LAN so anybody can connect to it and watch it. What steps do I need to do to accomplish this in an easy manner.

Comment: Recommend VLC shares http://code.google.com/p/vlc-shares/

Comment: @run ... I tried your solution and yes when I go to the url rstp link I get asked how I would like to open it...I use VLC and then it says "Error...Cannot stream" or something like that. Did you find the same thing initially if so how did you manage to stop it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a command line to stream webcam:

```
vlc v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=640 :v4l2-height=480 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/live.ts}" -I dummy
```

Comment: could you give some more explanations & give an example of reading the rtsp with vlc too on client side, it would enhance the answer which is great thx!

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Media > Stream** and select appropriate tab (file, disk, network, capture device) **> Stream**

Then click <kbd>Next</kbd> and Check **display locally** (optional) and from the drop down box select **http:** and click <kbd>add</kbd>

Select desired port not in use and hit <kbd>Next</kbd>

Check **activate transcoding** and select desired output format (click tool icon next to dropdown box to configure bitrate and other specific settings) **> Next > Stream**.

If all is good, you should see your source displayed/playing locally.

To test the stream, go to another computer on your LAN and with VLC, go to **media > open network stream** and type `http://serverIP:portnumber` (replace serverIP and portnumber with actual values) and hit <kbd>Play</kbd>.

If all is good, your stream will connect and play quickly.

Comment: It's a good and correct answer, but could use a little bit of formatting. Kind of hard to follow.

Comment: @Nephente suggest an edit!